# How to properly use Fallthrough in C++ in switch case statements without break?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am getting error in following code snippets:

```
   case id_report:
        if (iM == INITIATE)
        {
            *out_MSG = RSRC_UP;
            return RSRC_UP;
        }
        [[fallthrough]];

    case id_initiate:
        if (iMessageType == INITIATE)
        {
            *policyIdx = RSRC_RQST;
            *out_MSG = STATUS_RQST;
            return STATUS_RQST;
        }
        [[fallthrough]];
```

Upon compilation I get following erorr:

```
MegaUtil.c:915:13: error: expected expression before ‘[’ token
             [[fallthrough]];
             ^
MegaUtil.c:915:15: error: ‘fallthrough’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             [[fallthrough]];
```

It seems I am not using fallthrough properly. 
How should I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: [`fallthrough` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough).

Comment: You are missing a colon after case id_report. That should fix the problem, as everything else looks good.

Comment: I think that was typo in writing code snippet in this question.

Comment: You use it correctly, I [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9fe65d0e31ebc95) the errors. Are you missing `-std=c++17` flag, or is your compiler simply too old?

Comment: I did follow this document, but I am not sure what is wrong. You see I did exactly same.

Comment: @cybodroid Can you compile the snippet I linked without errors?

Comment: I am checking for c++17 flag.

Comment: Yup @HolyBlackCat  I am missing c++17 flags. Thanks.

Comment: and I was able to compile your code snippets @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I was missing std=c++17 flag as mentioned by @HolyBlackCat